# Websocket connection failed

Tags: javascript, php, socket, websocket

Estoy investigando sobre los sockets de php y he creado un pequeño script para intentar hacer una conxión mediante los websockets de js y los sockets de php.

El caso es que estoy utilizando Ratchet y he seguido todos los pasos de la documentación (http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) pero la conexión me da fallo y no se por qué. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```js
//server.php

<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

```js
//Chat.php

<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    protected $clients;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;

        echo "Conexión establecida";
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;

        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }

}
```

```js
//index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sockets</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Conectar socket</button>

    <script>
       window.onload = () => {
            console.log('Funciona el script');

            var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/socketphp.test/bin/server.php');

            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");
            };

            conn.onerror = e => {
                console.log('Fallo al establecer la conexión');
            } 

            conn.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log(e.data);
            };

            // conn.send('Hello World!');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es mi estructura de directorios:

- socketphp

  - bin

    - server.php
  - src

    - Chat.php
  - vendor
  - composer.json
  - composer.lock
  - index.php

Ejecuto en la consola `php bin/server.php` y cuando accedo al navegador en `index.php` me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socketphp.test/bin/server.php' failed.

Y se muestra el `console.log`

> Fallo al establecer la conexión

que hay en `conn.onerror`.

No se donde está el fallo o que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Verificaste que el socket servidor en PHP pueda establecer una conexión?, verificaste que el servidor no se cierre apenas llegue a la ultima linea del script?, a mi algo que me ocurrio en mi aplicativo fue que como estaba usando en este caso `socket.io`  tenia que especificarle las `CORS` exactas de conexion en las cabeceras para poder conectarme al servidor, ya que de lo contrario siempre me fallaba, no se si eso tenga algo que ver en este caso, ya que investigue sobre ratchet y al parecer los protocolos son los mismos, asi que descartamos esto ultimo.

Comment: Si posees linux puedes hacer ping sostenido a ese puerto con `telnet` para verificar que la conexion se mantiene en pie, si no posees linux puedes ir a la ruta ejecutable de tu `php` y ejecutar el servidor desde la terminal `php rutaAlArchivo.php`, si el comando nunca termina el servidor se encuentra en linea y esta escuchando sin cerrarse, de lo contrario hay que mirar la conexion y como sostenerla.

Comment: Esto ultimo lo digo porque una vez intente usar `ElephantIO` para algo pero me di cuenta que apenas llegaba al final del script la conexion caducaba y las opciones para dejarlo en linea no eran recomendadas y de todas maneras nunca me llegaron a funcionar. Tampoco pude conectarme nunca con `ElephantIO`  y `socket.io` por lo que tuve que optar por otra opcion.